# Событие onclick кнопку с картинкой JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Все доброго времени суток. Создаю программно кнопку которая содержит в себе изображение и по нажатию на которую выполняется добавление записей в localstorage.
Делаю так:

```js
function insertRow(id) {
  var tbody = document.getElementById(id).getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
  var row;
  row = document.createElement("tr");
  row.setAttribute("id", "tr_id");
  var cellCounter = document.getElementById("myTable").rows.length;
  var td1 = document.createElement("td");
  var deleteButton = document.createElement("input");
  deleteButton.setAttribute("class", "deleteButton");
  deleteButton.src = "icons/delete.png";
  deleteButton.type = "image";
  deleteButton.onclick = "delButton('myTable');return false;"
  td1.appendChild(deleteButton);
  row.appendChild(td1);
  tbody.appendChild(row);
}

function delButton(id) {
  localStorage.setItem("add_del", document.getElementById("add_id").value);
}
```

Кнопка в ячейке таблицы создается, изображение подтягивается, а `.onсlick` не отрабатывает. Подскажите, как это исправить? Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Необходимо в качестве значения атрибута `onclick` указать функцию. Например

```
deleteButton.onclick = function(){
  delButton('myTable');
  return false;
}
```

Либо, что более правильно, воспользоваться методом `addEventListener`

```
deleteButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
  delButton('myTable');
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку! Разница между onclick и addEventListener в том, что второй способен вызвать несколько функций по одному нажатию?

Comment: @TheHateInMe, Хоть это и не вся разница, но одно из основных преимуществ. Так же к преимуществам можно отнести возможность определить фазу события (погружение или всплытие); Определённый данным образом обработчик не возможно перезаписать. Только удалить явным образом. Так же повешенные данным образом обработчики будут перечислены в DevTools Chrome. Наверное есть ещё и другие преимущества

Answer (score 0):

Потому что вы в онклик записали строку вместо функции

```
deleteButton.onclick = "delButton('myTable');return false;"
```

поправьте на функцию и будет работать

```
deleteButton.onclick = function() { delButton('myTable') }
```